# Problema recuperar informação via API no Dataverse

Tags: r

Estou com dificuldade para recuperar a informação, pela API "[R Client para repositórios do Dataverse](https://github.com/IQSS/dataverse-client-r)" seguindo os passos da documentação estou com seguinte erro:

```
could not find function "get_dataframe_by_doi"
```

Qualquer método utilizando me retorna esta mensagem. Estou usando RStudio, e configurei conforme a documentação ambiente.
Os passos de configuração são:

```
install.packages("dataverse")
remotes::install_github("iqss/dataverse-client-r")
Sys.setenv("DATAVERSE_SERVER" = "DATAVERSE_IP"
dataverse::dataverse_search('Dados')
```

Comment: Carregou o pacote na sessão do R com `library(dataverse)`?

Comment: @RuiBarradasm, sim carreguei o pacote dataverse